# Not able to catch exceptions because of SecurityTokenExpiredException' is ambiguous in the namespace

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-web-api

I am validating a JWT token via

```
Dim principal = tokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, validationParameters, securityToken)
```

the validation works as expected but I can't catch the specific exception. I tried via

```
Catch ex As Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenExpiredException
```

which is supposed to catch when token is Expired but I can't use that one as I get the following Error

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error BC30560 'SecurityTokenExpiredException' is ambiguous in the
> namespace
> 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens'. SoapToAPI   C:\Users\source\repos\SoapToAPI\Helper\JWTUtil.vb   197 Active

[image]

Comment: Use the Object Explorer (View Menu->Object Explorer) to search for `SecurityTokenExpiredException`.  You may have multiple assemblies referenced that define it.

Comment: I updated the Question with a Pic of the Search Result of ObjectBrowser and search for SecurityTokenExpiredException

Comment: Well the search results confirm that you have 2 different assemblies that contain `SecurityTokenExpiredException`. Now you need to click on each one and look at the lower right pane of the Object Explorer. This will tell you the assembly name if the "View Containers" option is selected in the settings (click on the dropdown furtherest to the right on the same line contains the word "Browse". It has a gear icon.). I should have also told you to select "Solution" for the Browse target. Update us with the path reported for each assembly.

Comment: FYI, i was on solution  here is what i got, the first one is `Public Class SecurityTokenExpiredException
        Inherits SecurityTokenValidationException
    Member of Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens`  the second one is  `Public Class SecurityTokenExpiredException
        Inherits Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenValidationException
    Member of Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens

Summary:
Throw this exception when a received Security Token has expiration time in the past.`

Comment: As this drove me nuts i did some more digging and found the source of the issue. My project had as a reference the Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens  as well as the Microsoft.IdentityModel once i deleted the Microsoft.IdentityModel reference the issue was gone. I guess this was added via some import statement automaticly

Comment: Sorry, I omitted a few steps in my instructions.  We are looking for the file path of each assembly that defines `SecurityTokenValidationException`.  After doing the search. click on the first line of a found node. Then click the "Clear Search" button. This should return you to the full treeview with that node still selected. Scroll up until you reach the root node that contains the entry. That will be the Assembly node.  Select it and copy the file path. Repeat the search and get the path of the other one.  Then you can look at the properties of each reference in the solution explore to find

Comment: the matching file paths.  At that point you have to determine why you have two references that contain the same namespace.